# What is the logic behind the "order of applying filters" in Apache Lucene

Tags: java, apache, lucene, analyzer

I have implemented my own analyzer in Apache Lucene for specific purposes. There are certain filters to apply before a term is getting indexed. I thought it wouldn't matter to change the application order of filters. But it seems like it does. For example;

```
analyzer = new Analyzer(){ 
      @Override
      protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName){
        AttributeFactory factory = AttributeFactory.DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE_FACTORY;
        Tokenizer source = new NGramTokenizer(factory,3,10);
        TokenStream filter = new NewlineFilter(source);
        filter = new LowerCaseFilter(filter);
        filter = new UsefulGrams(getVersion(), filter, usefulGramSet);
        filter = new EmptySpaceFilter(filter);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source,filter);
      };
  };
```

My tokenizer is generating grams, then newlines are cut and all cases lowered. After this, I want only the grams that I find "useful" shall be in the index, that filter eliminates the useless grams. At the end, it filters out the grams that consist fully of empty spaces.

With the data set I hold, this order generates 316 indexed terms. But if I change the order of filters;

```
analyzer = new Analyzer(){ 
      @Override
      protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName){
        AttributeFactory factory = AttributeFactory.DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE_FACTORY;
        Tokenizer source = new NGramTokenizer(factory,3,10);
        TokenStream filter = new UsefulGrams(getVersion(), source, usefulGramSet);
        filter = new NewlineFilter(filter);
        filter = new EmptySpaceFilter(filter);
        filter = new LowerCaseFilter(filter);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source,filter);
      };
  };
```

This produces 350 indexed terms. Notice the "first" filter has to use SOURCE TOKENIZER, but the other ones use FILTER TOKENSTREAM. 
If I put SOURCE in every parameter, it gives warnings related to "addsuppression".

My question is, what should be the order of applying these filters? I want to apply all these (all lowercase, just the terms I choose, without empty grams, without newlines), wouldn't think this be changed by anything, apparently it does.

Comment: It seems that, only on some occasions indexed term number changes, the problem seems to be occurring from something else....

Answer (score 2):

Yes, order matters.  Filters are applied to the text in sequence.

This matters when the action of one filter will affect the outcome of another filter.  This is pretty easy to see happen with stemmers.

If I have a SynonymFilter sith the synonym (viking -> seafarer), and an EnglishStemFilter, then viking will end up

- SynonymFilter:  viking -> seafarer
- EnglishStemFilter: seafarer -> seafar

If I put the stemmer before the SynonymFilter:

- EnglishStemFilter:  viking -> vike
- SynonymFilter: vike (no effect)

As far as the correct ordering for your analyzer, I don't know.  The main question seems to be on where to put the `UsefulGrams` filter, and I have no idea what that actually does.